# Write '-(e)s' in italic or not?

Tags: plural-forms, abbreviations

When using certain abbreviations in italic, should '-(e)s' representing plural form written in italic?

For example,

> We call a mobile node that senses the surrounding information *MN*.
>
> Blah, blah, blah ...
>
> The *MNs* in a region R will be ~~~~~~~~.

v.s.

> We call a mobile node that senses the surrounding information *MN*.
>
> Blah, blah, blah ...
>
> The *MN*s in a region R will be ~~~~~~~~.

Only the last sentences are different (*MNs* v.s. *MN*s).
Which is more correct for the formal papers?

Comment: Such questions are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a style manual appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Answer (score -2):

Here, "*MN*s" is the only correct form which should always be followed while pluralizing Numbers or Acronyms, i.e. One should not write '-(e)s' in italics while italicizing the Number or Acronym.

Hope, [this](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/11/pluralize-numbers-and-abbreviations-without-apostrophes.html) blog will help you to find this out.

Comment: Welcome!  Your answer that “is the **only** correct form” is a very strong statement that needs some support beyond a blog.  Are there any recognized style guides that support this?

Comment: @whiskeychief, Actually, I am new to StackExchange so I don't know the perfect way to answer a question here. I am sorry if I have violated guidelines by answering so emphatically. It was all my personal opinion and that particular blog. I will take care of such mistakes in future.And thanks for making me realize the problem with my answer.

Comment: Thank you and please continue to contribute!  There is a very good FAQ and contributor’s guide which is worth reading.  Keep it up!